# Cypher / Efficiency about relationship cardinality

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Using Neo4j 2.X and Cypher, I want to query all `Users` that I know directly or via a friend.

I would expect something like this:

```
MATCH (me:User("123"))-[:KNOWS*1..2]-(friend)  //does not work of course
```

I think about the `shortestPath` function, but wouldn't it be too expensive?

Moreover, if I have this query:

```
MATCH (a)-[:SOME_REL]->(b)<-[:OWNS_BY]-(me:User("123"))   // would load the whole in memory before filtering by knowledge !
WITH shortestPath((me)-[:KNOWS*..2]-(friend)) as path
WHERE path.length <= 2
```

OR

```
MATCH (a)-[:SOME_REL]->(b)<-[:OWNS_BY]-(me:User("123"))   // would load the whole in memory before filtering by knowledge !
MATCH path = shortestPath((me)-[:KNOWS*..2]-(friend))
WHERE path.length <= 2
```

**Wouldn't it be more (maybe too in the case of a huge graph?) expensive?**

Indeed, this would be better, if it worked:

```
MATCH (a)-[:SOME_REL]->(b)<-[:OWNS_BY]-(me:User("123"))-[:KNOWS*1..2]-(friend)
```

loading in memory only appropriate path.

I could also use an alternative like this:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:SOME_REL]->(b)<-[:OWNS_BY]-(me:User("123"))-[:KNOWS]-(friend)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:SOME_REL]->(b)<-[:OWNS_BY]-(me:User("123"))-[:KNOWS]-()-[:KNOWS]-(friend)
```

but imagine if I wanted three degrees of separation (for knowledge)... the query would be very redundant.

**Is there a good syntax that would lead to a very efficient query?**
What should I use?

Comment: Why doesn't the first query work?

Comment: I just read the doc, and didn't found this pattern except for `shortestPath`.. I thought that the pattern was exclusive to `shortestPath` so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand, and I think that your first query would work?

```
MATCH (me:User{userId:123})-[:KNOWS*1..2]-(friend:User)
WHERE me <> friend
RETURN friend
```

It's hard to know what to write for the other queries as the OWNS_BY and SOME_REL components seem unrelated to the friend of a friend component, if you could relate the two halves of the query with a concrete example I can explain an optimal approach.

Some key pointers are that you should

1. Start your queries with what you think will match the minimum set of nodes (to constrain the work that has to be done).
2. Make sure all query components utilise labels and relationship types.
3. Create indexes on properties that you will be using in lookups.

An excellent resource for query optimisation is [Wes Freeman's Pragmatic Optimisation](http://wes.skeweredrook.com/pragmatic-cypher-optimization-2-0-m06/).

The size of the graph does not need to make the queries more expensive as you will mostly be working on a subgraph which presumably have more fixed sized bounds. Of course if your queries need to span the entire graph then the size will become an issue for speed!

Comment: "the OWNS_BY and SOME_REL components seem unrelated to the friend of a friend component" => indeed, it's just a sample. You wrote: "Start your queries with what you think will match the minimum set of nodes". Does it mean that this query should be split?:  `MATCH (a)-[:SOME_REL]->(b)<-[:OWNS_BY]-(me:User("123"))-[:KNOWS*1..2]-(friend) WHERE me <> friend RETURN friend` ? If I split it like the following: `MATCH (a)-[:SOME_REL]->(b)<-[:OWNS_BY]-(me:User("123"))
MATCH (me)-[:KNOWS*1..2]-(friend:User)
WHERE me <> friend
RETURN friend`, does it waste some memory?

Comment: Thanks for the Wes's link, I understand the benefit of splitting now ;). : starting with the minimal match ( in terms of returned nodes) that will filter the whole, in order to simplify and ease the second match.